# Where can I download old versions of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, download, xcode10, xcode11, dmg

I am able to download the current versions of Xcode and other resources from the Apple Developer Center(s), but where can I download older versions?

Specifically, I am looking for recent older Xcode

Comment: Have you tried working with Xcode 3.2.6 to see if works for your specific needs? Why are you looking for an earlier version?

Comment: @mopsled , will it still work fine on a leopard 10.5.8 osx? I am going to a workshop for ruby on rails, and those are the instructions they gave us beforehand.

Comment: Try downloading, see if it works... I know it takes a while but I think that is the best way to find out.

Comment: @deceze, Marina: No - it won't work. Latest version requires Lion.

Comment: @vcsjones She does not want the latest version.

Comment: @josherick, I know that. Another commenter said "Just use the latest version because they are outdated".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**2021 Update**

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

It requires signing in with a free Apple Developer account.

[image: screenshot showing old xcode downloads]

Comment: I have gone there, and it only lists 3.2.6. You can check for yourself, if you'd like.

Comment: Scroll down the page. See the above image. If you can't find it, CMD-F and search for the version number.

Comment: This is totally the right answer. It is worth noting, though, that you might not see what you're looking for at first glance, because there are multiple pages of developer tools at the referenced site. By now, XCode 3.1.4 is old enough that it appears on page 6 (of 8 pages) -- but it **is** still there.

Comment: Update for **step3**, click **See more downloads** in the bottom of the **Resources** page.(update on 2018-9-25)

Comment: There is no "resources" link anymore.

Comment: @AaronFranke the path is a little different now but you can still find it. From your account page see the menu on the left side and click "Downloads". This will show you "Beta" section of the downloads, change it in the upper right hand side - there is Beta, Release and More. Tap More. There you can find all previous Xcode versions...

Comment: The path has changed, and you can find the new downloads page at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: http://xcodereleases.com has a comprehensive list of previous versions of Xcode with download and release notes links to apple.com.

Answer (score 35):

The following link filters for "Xcode" in the Apple Developer Center downloads repository:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

This link seems fairly future-proof?

The links have changed since the accepted answer to this question was written; I could not find a link to "Downloads" after clicking "Resources".

Previously, this URL was used:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. The link still works now in 2018.

Comment: Not working anymore

Comment: @atilkan it still works for me, although there are a lot of items and the sorting is weird. You can also search for a specific version for better results.

Comment: It appears that Apple has changed the URL. I found it here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Actually both links are working

Answer (score 27):

You can download recent versions of `Xcode` from below links.

> **Xcode 13 RC**

> - [Xcode 13 RC](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13_Release_Candidate/Xcode_13_Release_Candidate.xip)
>
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 13 RC) - for macOS BigSur +)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13_Release_Candidate/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13_Release_Candidate.dmg)

**Xcode 11**

- [Xcode 11.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2/Xcode_11.2.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 11.2 beta 2) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2_beta_2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2_beta_2.dmg)
- [Xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11/Xcode_11.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 11) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.dmg)

**Xcode 10**

- [Xcode 10.2.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2.1/Xcode_10.2.1.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.2.1) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.1.dmg/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.1.dmg)
- [Xcode 10.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2/Xcode_10.2.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.2) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.dmg)
- [Xcode 10.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.1) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg)   
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10.1) - for macOS
  10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg)
- [Xcode 10](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10/Xcode_10.xip) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS
  10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.dmg) 
   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS
  10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.dmg)

> For non-premium account/apple id: (Download Xcode 10 without Paid (Premium) Apple Developer Account from below link)

> - [Xcode 10.1 (Mac App Store Link)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

[Apple Download Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

See here for older versions of Xcode (Which may need to authenticate your apple account):

- **Xcode 9**
- [9.4.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.4.1/Xcode_9.4.1.xip)
- [9.3.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.3.1/Xcode_9.3.1.xip)
- [9.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.3/Xcode_9.3.xip)
- [9.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip)
- [9.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.1/Xcode_9.1.xip)
- [9.0.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.0.1/Xcode_9.0.1.xip)
- [9.0](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.0/Xcode_9.0.xip)
- **Xcode 8**
- [8.3.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.3/Xcode8.3.3.xip)
- [8.3.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.2/Xcode8.3.2.xip)
- [8.3.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.1/Xcode_8.3.1.xip)
- [8.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3/Xcode_8.3.xip)
- [8.2.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.2.1/Xcode_8.2.1.xip)
- [8.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.2/Xcode_8.2.xip)
- [8.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.1/Xcode_8.1.xip)
- [8.0](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8/Xcode_8.xip)
- **Xcode 7**
- [7.3.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg)
- [7.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg)
- [7.2.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2.1/Xcode_7.2.1.dmg)
- [7.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2/Xcode_7.2.dmg)
- [7.1.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1.1/Xcode_7.1.1.dmg)
- [7.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1/Xcode_7.1.dmg)
- [7.0.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.0.1/Xcode_7.0.1.dmg)
- [7.0](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7/Xcode_7.dmg)

[Apple Download Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

Answer (score 11):

It's moved recently. From developer.apple.com go to More in top right corner

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

Go to iOS Development center (iOS gives you Xcode plus the iPhone tools if Im correct) Mac Development Center will probably work too.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Scroll down to DOWNLOADS Xcode 4.4.1
You will see: "Looking for an older version of Xcode? Download"

Click that .

I found it on page 3 - way at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Apple's dev Portal (sign in required) - The More Downloads section https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
2. Search for the relevant Xcode version.
3. Expand the row and click the download link

Comment: This is the most up to date answer. March 2019.

Comment: Was about to post this, but no need now.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 3.2.x is documented as only being for OS X 10.6.x (Snow Leopard).  As far as I know, Xcode 3.1.4 is the most recent version of Xcode for OS X 10.5.  While it seems to be hidden away, I found it was possible to get to the old links for it, if you are registered at the Apple Developer Connection website, by using this link:

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/downloads

and then clicking through to the "Developer Tools" section and scrolling down to the download link for "Xcode 3.1.4".  I'm not sure why Apple has made it that hard to find older stuff.  Perhaps they are trying to get people to join the paid Mac Developer program?

UPDATE: I see this is the same link that Evan's suggestion eventually gets you to.    They could make the links a little more obvious, especially from the Xcode page itself!

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is anyway to download an older version. I bet the website you are following was made when xcode 3.1.4 was the newest version. You could try searching for torrents of the version of xcode you want, but the might be dead since the version you want is older.

Why do you need 3.1.4, instead of 3.2.6? Does 3.2.6 not work with Leopard?

You can go [here](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792) to download 3.2.6, I think you need a free account.

Comment: The apple developers website says it is for snow leopard. I think 3.1.4 was the latest version of Xcode that would work for Leopard.

Comment: I would try 3.2.6 unless you can find a torrent for 3.1.4

Comment: Are there any websites you would suggest to find this torrent?

Comment: "Xcode 3.2 was released with Mac OS X v10.6 'Snow Leopard' and will not install on any earlier version of Mac OS X." according to the wikipedia page on Xcode.

Comment: ok, go for a torrent. sorry, i dont know of any way to go.