# I can't upgrade Xcode. What can I do?

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode8

I have Xcode version 8.3

macOS: 10.12.6 (I can´t upgrade)

rect-native: 0.59.5

watchman: 4.9.0

I can't upgrade because my Mac is too old and the project that comes with the react native is for the new version of Xcode.

What can I do?

All this is because I can´t program in react-native that is not compatible white Xcode 8 the new version and I can´t use and oldest version.

I have looked for previous versions I downloaded from Github. RN Version 0.55.4 there says that is for Xcode 8.3 but that doesn't work.

how do you program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download old versions of Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047735/where-can-i-download-old-versions-of-xcode)

Comment: You need a new(er) Mac that runs macOS 10.13 or later. Apple requires all new app submissions to be built with Xcode 10.1 or later. Xcode 10.1 needs macOS 10.13.4 or later. It would be even better to get a Mac that will run macOS 10.15 coming out in just a few months. Otherwise you will be stuck again in another year when Apple raises the requirement again.

Answer (score 0):

You can download any previous or current version (from 7.0 up to 10.2) of XCode using links, listed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652775/10556960

You will need to sign in with your Apple Developer account at `developer.apple.com`, tho.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com), the latest Xcode that runs on macOS 10.12.6 is Xcode 9.2.